# What is the request-per-minute rate limit for Azure openAI models for gpt-3.5-turbo?

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I couldn't find the RPM limit for Azure openAI

I found the TPM limit thou which is 240k for East US, South Central US, West Europe, France Central, UK South,

I've tried Microsoft documentation but couldn't find this limit.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/quotas-limits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "RPM" (request per minute) quota is directly a rate of the "TPM" (transaction per minute):

[image: RPM calculation]

So for GPT 3.5 Turbo models, if you have a 240k TPM for your deployment, the RPM will be 1440 requests per minute.

Example visible in Azure AI Studio: in my case, I set a 120k TPM, I got 720 RPM:

[image: quotas example]

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/quota?tabs=rest#introduction-to-quota

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas, that is exactly what I was after 